# Can I get 5 rep change for an upvote on -an answer-?

Tags: support

Don't get me wrong, I always enjoy the rep, but today made me curious, I got five reps for an upvote on an answer, *and* ten on the same day:

[image]

Can't remember this ever happened to me before. 
Tiny bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got +5 from an upvote on the *question*, not the answer. You simply happened to receive an upvote on both the question and the answer today, hence +10 for the answer and +5 for the question.

Comment: I don't think so, the question wasn't mine.

Comment: [timeline shows the upvote](https://askubuntu.com/posts/483687/timeline)

Comment: Omg, it was! Shame on me. Think I need a vacation, or maybe mine was too long :)

Answer (score 4):

I've checked your profile and yes, that is absolutely possible, you've got one upvote for your question (**= 5** reputation **points**) and you've got another upvote for your own answer (**= 10** reputation **points**). Obviously you seem to be new to the Stack Exchange system ... hope you don't mind the joke. :)

Comment: Haha, sure. I deserve it. I remembered *answering* the question, but remembered it as answering a question of someone else. Was pretty sure of it. Didn't even check.